# ReactJS Webpack : ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader, webpack-5

I'm using webpack in React JS. and Here is my error,

ERROR in   Error: /Users/prakash/Desktop/projects/limitscale/goal.ly/goaly-react/src:58758
var theme = window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches
^
ReferenceError: window is not defined

- src:58758 Object../node_modules/react-axe/dist/index.js
  /Users/prakash/Desktop/projects/limitscale/goal.ly/goaly-react/src:58758:13
- src:113496 **webpack_require**
  /Users/prakash/Desktop/projects/limitscale/goal.ly/goaly-react/src:113496:42
- src:38954 Module../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.js
  /Users/prakash/Desktop/projects/limitscale/goal.ly/goaly-react/src:38954:13
- src:113496 **webpack_require**
  /Users/prakash/Desktop/projects/limitscale/goal.ly/goaly-react/src:113496:42
- src:113646
  /Users/prakash/Desktop/projects/limitscale/goal.ly/goaly-react/src:113646:18
- src:113647
  /Users/prakash/Desktop/projects/limitscale/goal.ly/goaly-react/src:113647:12
- index.js:321 HtmlWebpackPlugin.evaluateCompilationResult
  [goaly-react]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:321:28
- index.js:237
  [goaly-react]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:237:22
- task_queues.js:93 processTicksAndRejections
  internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5

and my webpack config file,

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');


const ROOT_DIRECTORY = path.join(__dirname, '..')
const SRC_DIRECTORY = path.join(ROOT_DIRECTORY, 'src')
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const plugins = [];
plugins.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.join(SRC_DIRECTORY, '')
  })
  );
plugins.push( new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    patterns: [
        { from: path.join(SRC_DIRECTORY, 'assets'), to: path.join(ROOT_DIRECTORY, 'build') }
    ],
  }));

plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin())

const config = {
  entry: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.js')],
  output: {
    globalObject: "this",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
    // filename: 'bundle.js',
    filename: '[name].[hash:8].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].[hash:8].map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash:8].js',
    publicPath: '/',

  },
  mode: 'development',
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve('node_modules'), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: [".jsx", ".js"]
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  plugins: plugins  ,
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader"
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "html-loader"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(s*)css$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader'
            ]
        },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|png|svg)$/, 
        use: ['url-loader?limit=10000']
      }
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = config
```

What should I do to avoid this error?
Facing this issue for a while. Couldn't able to figure out. Is there any error in my code?.New to webpack.